# Incorrect card number when swiping with Magtek Card Reader

Tags: payment, credit-card, financial, magnetic-cards

I'm am currently working on a POS web app, where we use the credit card swipe functionality. I'm planning to use the card reader: 
[MagTek 21073062 Dynamag Magnesafe Triple Track Magnetic Stripe Swipe Reader with 6' USB Interface Cable, 5V, Black](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EUMXIW6)

I tried out swiping the credit card and get my final card data as follows:

"%B4111111111111111^FIRST/LAST^1010000000000000000000000000000?;4111111111111111=11111111111111119080000000000000000?|0600|F8861EC73F7BD2790D4EE2DBB7935B039DE9653DE90D240C1257E225FBB987837B779D29246D9D516A94FE9F770396FE6AD2A5F3312108DF35BB512F4BA22A84FF3BB6CDFC008024|669078686F127D2A0660BBBE6C7BD3F708ED1B42216F41E37F3DCF59DB02C77452337456C9F5141D||61403000|190894CFA8A9E46A350C2E758DC1D83A798980BF5319298583E13DC98C62272C8C732D07B2713B1FACE8DBF6CE16B57C94360610CD6FFE46|B2E15B9061015AA|789A6E205C421D40|9011080B2E15B9004018|1CA3||1000"

Data interpreted to according to [Financial Cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_stripe_card)

The card number according the response above,  the card number is "4111111111111111"(for representation purpose). The problem is the number in the response is not correct. The first 6 digits and the last 4 digits seems to be fine, but the digits(6 in this case) in the middle seems to be incorrect(does not match with the swiped card). This happens to all the cards I swipe. Tried the same card multiple times(to check if hardware problem) , still the same result.

Any help on this issue will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes I have. All the cards show the same issue.

Comment: Your link *MagTek 21073062...* is not a link...

Comment: Sorry about that. The link is as follows:
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00EUMXIW6/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1.
This is just the link to the product in the amazon

Comment: The amazon link describes how the product returns a masked version of the PAN, and an encrypted version. You'll need to write decryption routines. Looks like the technical documentation is mainly contained within the user guide here: https://www.magtek.com/content/documentationfiles/d99875475.pdf

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem as described is based on a misunderstanding of how the product should be used.

Comment: @PaulG could you let me know on how to unmask the masked PAN

Comment: What is command in magtek..i have download it demo but couldn't understand what is command may you please expain me.

Comment: Could you comment on your decryption process step by step? There are some nuances to Magtek decryption that might cause it

Comment: I don't think we need to unmask the information here. We actually have to send the masked data to the Endpoints provided by Magtek doc which is designed to understand this data